# RExcel in R 3.0.x

Tags: r, rexcel

[**RAndFriends**](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download.html#RAndFriends), which includes all the items needed to run `RExcel`, includes just `R 2.15.2`.

I am currently using the latest version of `R` but `rcom 2.3.1` and `rscproxy 2.0.5`, which I am currently using, do not allow me to start an `R` server within Excel.

Setting foreground `R` server whithin Excel returns a fatal error and `R` rejects any connection with Excel via `rcom`.

I get two error messages:

1. `R Server not available`
2. `There seems to be no R process connected to Excel`

The main difference with a running `RExcel` session is that in the latter you may see `rscproxy` and `rcom` to be loaded when you start a `RExcel` session.

Is there anyone who is currently using `RExcel` with `R 3.0.1` who can explain me how he succeeded in running it (step by step)?

Comment: Please post exact content of your fatal error. Have you tried running it in 32 bit R? I use RODBC to connect to Excel files and the 64 bit R can't handle these connections.

Comment: i only could get Rexcel to work with earlier versions of R

Comment: I'm doing everything on a 32 bit Windows machine; by the way, I tried with a 64 bit Windows machine, too... no difference at all. I'm going to post error details later.

Comment: Edited to show error messages.

Comment: As this is a question specifically directed towards statconn products, I would try to contact them: http://rcom.univie.ac.at/contact.html. This mentions a mailing list for the free users, for the paid version they provide more concrete help directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it on statconn's Wiki section.

Assuming you have a suitable version of `R` installed, the following steps are necessary to install `RExcel` and the infrastructure. You need to be logged into Windows with administrator privileges to do this!

You also need to follow these instructions if you upgrade `R`, i.e. you install a new release of `R` after you have installed `RExcel`.

1. Download the [**statconn DCOM server**](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download/current/statconnDCOM.latest.exe) and execute the program you downloaded.
2. Start `R` as administrator (on Windows 7 you need to right-click the `R` icon and click the corresponding item).
3. In `R`, run the following commands (you must start `R` as administrator to do this).

Commands:

```
install.packages(c("rscproxy", "rcom"), repos = "http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download", lib = .Library)
library(rcom)
comRegisterRegistry()
```

Now you have `rcom` installed, but `RExcel` is not installed yet.

To install `RExcel`: download the [**RExcel installer**](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download/RExcel.distro/RExcelInst.latest.exe) and run this installation program. Installing `RExcel` this way will set the background server of `R` as the default `R` server for `RExcel`. You can change this in the configuration settings in `R`. If you want to set the foreground server as the default site wide server, there is an appropriate option in one of the dialogs of the installation.

The `RExcel` installer modifies one of the configuration files of `R`, the file `Rprofile.site`, usually found at a location like `C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.1\etc\Rprofile.site`.

If you do not install `RExcel` and want the package `rcom` to be loaded into `R` each time you start it, you have to add the line

```
library(rcom)
```

to `Rprofile.site`. You have to start your editor as administrator to be able to modify this file.

Comment: That is one great answer. It delays the moment I adapt RDCOMServer for my needs

Answer (score 3):

I thint that focus of those instuctions are on "Assuming you have a suitable version of R installed". R 3.0.1 do not work with RExcel.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed all development of Rmetrics products have ceased development since Diethelm Wuertz untimely passing, some of his associates on the team maintain it, but further development stopped abruptly after Diethelm Wuertz the project leader and main inspiration behind the team, died in a car accident in 2015, that is how long it has been since any serious development has occurred on Rexcel and all the range of Rmetric products, it is a real tragedy they are still cutting edge 6 years after Diethelm's passing, he would be sad to see his legacy slowly die. I am looking at xlwings and converting not too difficult code to python for speed and power, as far as many great R libraries go, I have not the time to reinvent the wheel within python, it is not a labour of love for me.